# How can I watch all addresses under HD wallet?

Tags: bitcoind, bip32-hd-wallets, watch-only

Is there any way to watch all addresses under HD wallet?

I'd like to notify users when any of addresses in a HD wallet receive BTC.

- It looks like bitcoind (walletnotify) doesn't support HD wallet. You have to add many addresses into a wallet to watch them.
- blockchain.info xpub API? (I'm not sure how the API can handle it.)

  - It seems there is no web service for watch-only HD wallet. [Is there any web-service to watch(only) HD Wallet BIP32? : Bitcoin](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/2px6o8/is_there_any_webservice_to_watchonly_hd_wallet/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm [BlockCypher's](http://www.blockcypher.com/) Developer Advocate.

We have a series of HD Wallet Endpoints that we recently released that might suit your needs; you can read more about it here:

http://dev.blockcypher.com/#hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets

You can use it in tandem with our [WebHooks API](http://dev.blockcypher.com/#events-and-hooks) for notifications whenever an address associated with an HD wallet is involved in a transaction.

If you want to use something locally instead of our API, I'm a fan of btcd and their associated [btcwallet](https://github.com/btcsuite/btcwallet), which supports HD addresses.

Answer (score 2):

> It seems there is no web service for watch-only HD wallet. Is there any >web-service to watch(only) HD Wallet BIP32? : Bitcoin

Actually there is. Check out [blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co) , it supports xpub search and also wallet watcher with xpub support that sends out email notifications on transactions.  Also has websocket API for notfications

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend a third-party service for this, we use both:

**https://blockchainwebhooks.com**

and

**https://blockcypher.com**

Both services work great and are reliable. Blockchain WebHooks is much more affordable longer term